# ReferenceError: client is not defined

Tags: discord.js

I dont know why I am getting this error this is my code.
Can anyone help me with this please? That would be nice.

```js
const discord = require("discord.js");
const moment = require("moment");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {

    var member = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]));
    if(!member) member = message.member;

    var roles = member.roles.cache.size - 1;
    var roleNames = member.roles.cache.map(r => r).join(" ").replace("@everyone", "");
    if(roles == 0) roleNames = "Geen rollen";

    var status = member.presence.status;

    var nickName = member.nickname;
    if(nickName == null || undefined) nickName = "Geen";

    var embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#00ff00")
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({size: 4096}))
        .setTitle(`${member.user.tag}`)
        .addField("ID:", `${member.id}`, true)
        .addField("Bijnaam:", nickName, true)
        .addField("Status:", `${status}`, true)
        .addField("Game", `${member.presence.activities[0] ? member.presence.activities[0].name : 'Geen'}`, true)
        .addField("Account gemaakt", `${moment(member.user.createdAt).format("LL")}`)
        .addField(`Rollen [ ${roles}]`, `${roleNames}`);

    message.channel.send(embed);

}
    

module.exports.help = {
    name: "userinfo"
}
```

The problem is on line 6 and here's that code on line 6

```js
var member = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you passed in client as "bot". Just replace client with bot.

Comment: If it works, accept the answer so that others who has undefined problems will be able to know.